# Download CSV is not working in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, csv

```
     uri = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + escape(str);  // str contain csv data

     var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
     downloadLink.href = uri;
     downloadLink.download = "test.csv";

     document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
     downloadLink.click();
     document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
```

code is working in chrome ,but not working in internet explorer getting some issue like SCRIPT122: The data area passed to a system call is too small.
i need to work it with ie 8 and without using server, please give some solution ,
thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

CanIUse.com indicates that IE10/11 do not support the download attribute on links.

see http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Your options are ping-pong with a server and telling users to use another browser.

Comment: thanks for reply. but here not used any server, it need to run on local machine.

Comment: Works locally on Google Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for IE,

```
    var IEwindow = window.open();
    IEwindow.document.write('sep=,\r\n' + CSV);
    IEwindow.document.close();
    IEwindow.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName + ".csv");
    IEwindow.close();
```

see - [Download JSON data in CSV format Cross Browser Support](http://code.ciphertrick.com/2014/12/07/download-json-data-in-csv-format-cross-browser-support/)

Hope this will be helpful for you.